# Add column to a table in desired column sequence number

Tags: sql-server

I am adding a new column to the table using alter table command, i want the column to be added in specific column index for example 5, is there an easy way to do it? Can someone help me out on this. Tried verifying in google but no answers found.

Comment: No you can't do that and why would you want to?

Comment: Just select your columns in the desired order.

Comment: That such a question is asked suggests a code smell in your application: instead of inserting data anonymously, `INSERT dbo.Table VALUES (Val1, Val2, Val3);`, you should be specifying the target column names, `INSERT dbo.Table (Col1, Col2, Col3) VALUES (Val1, Val2, Val3);`... then it never matters which order columns are created in, inserts always work correctly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Not really. It would often be nice if we could have logically related columns together without having the ordering constrained by when we happened to add them. Just because SQL Server doesn't decouple this and so it is not possible in current versions without recreating the table (and we have presumably learned to accept that) doesn't mean there is a code smell to look for this functionality.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think, given their lack of experience, it would be a fair guess that OP is either trying to `select *` and expecting a particular order or `insert` without listing the columns. Else they would have responded by now explaining their use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, the position of a column within a table is determined by the order in which the columns were defined when the table was created. As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't provide a direct SQL command to move a column to a specific position. However, you can achieve a similar result by creating a new table with the desired column order and then copying the data from the old table.

CAUTION: Keep in mind that this approach involves temporarily duplicating the data, so it's essential to perform these operations during a maintenance window or when the system can tolerate some downtime. Additionally, it's always a good practice to have a backup of your data before making significant changes to the table structure.

Comment: Technically correct, but probably better to question why OP feels the need to do this, because normally it indicates they are doing something else wrong